# Multiple dispatchHandler Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, events, dispatchevent

I want to dispatch an Event 2 times:

I have a MainClass, a SecondClass and a ThirdClass.

In the ThirdClass, there's a clickEvent. I dispatch it to the SecondClass:

```
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);


    public static const CLICKED_HANDLER:String = "clickedHandler";

    public function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(CLICKED_HANDLER));
    }
```

I catch and throw it in the SecondClass:

```
    object.addEventListener(ThirdClass.CLICKED_Handler, clickedEventListener);


    public static const CLICKED_HANDLER:String = "clickedHandler";

    public function clickedEventListener(e:Event):void {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(CLICKED_HANDLER));
    }
```

And this I catch in the MainClass:

```
    object.addEventListener(SecondClass.CLICKED_HANDLER, clickedEventListener);

    public function clickedEventListener(e:Event):void {
        trace("click");
    }
```

But it wouldn't work... What am I doing wrong?
And how could I get information about the object of the ThirdClass that's clicked?
(Normaly with 1 dispatchEvent, it's with:

```
    var thirdClassObject:ThirdClass = e.currentTarget as ThirdClass;
```

in the clickHandler method, but how to do this with 2 dispatchEvents?)

So: I want to know in my MainClass which ThirdClass-object is clicked.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you dispatch an event, the `target` property references the dispatcher.
What you apparently need is passing a reference to third class along with the event to use in the event handler of main class.

You have several options to achieve this.

1. If a dispatcher instance is on the display list, use [event bubbling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e54.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e46) to handle events in parent display objects. Refer to the [second argument](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#Event%28%29) of `Event` constructor and [Event.bubbles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#bubbles) property. This way you can subscribe to any events of child objects in a parent, and check `Event.target` property in your event handler. Most of mouse events like `MouseEvent.CLICK` are bubbling by default. So you could just listen to them and check targets in main class.

   ```
   // inside MainClass
   // notice: we are subscribing to MainClass instance
   this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickedEventListener);

   public function clickedEventListener(e:MouseEvent):void {
       trace(e.target); // the target is what was actually clicked
       // you may also notice the difference between e.target and e.currentTarget
   }
   ```

   If you still want to use `CLICKED_HANDLER` event, you may do so as follows:

   ```
   // inside ThirdClass
   dispatchEvent(new Event(CLICKED_HANDLER, true));
   // ---------------------------------------^
   ```

   Remember: this will only work for display list members.
   See the [Event flow article on adobe.com](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e4f.html).
2. Create a [custom event class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e55.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e48) and place reference there. (And you can also use event bubbling with custom event classes.) This way you will dispatch your event as

   ```
   // inside SecondClass
   public function clickedEventListener(e:Event):void {
       var customEvent:CustomEventClass = new CustomEventClass(CLICKED_HANDLER);
       customEvent.customTarget = e.target;
       dispatchEvent(customEvent);
   }

   // inside MainClass
   public function clickedEventListener(e:CustomEventClass):void {
       trace(e.customTarget );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First, define what do you mean by "it wouldn't work..."?

Does the SecondClass receive the event at all? If so, you may try this:

```
//SecondClass
public function clickedEventListener(e:Event):void {
    dispatchEvent(e);
}

//MainClass
object.addEventListener(ThirdClass.CLICKED_HANDLER, clickedEventListener);
```